# How to set User in request.user in Django using MongoDB

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

How i can set my own user in `request.user` or `request.session.user`
my own models:

```
class User(Document):
    id = fields.IntField(primary_key=True)
    username = fields.StringField(required=True)
    email = fields.EmailField()
    ....
    @property
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return False
```

I set this in my view

```
user = User.objects.get(email=email)
request.session.user = user
```

but didn't work.

Comment: If you want manage a user, i think that you have to extend the user model insted on django. Read this tutorial: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set an attribute on `session` object the way you're trying to do.

But you can set a **key** in the `session` object (since it's just like a dictionary), like this:

```
# you can't set a user object directly
# because it's not JSON serializable
# but you can set its `id`
request.session['user_id'] = user.id
```

Later, you can get the user like this:

```
user_id = request.session.get('user_id', None)
if user_id:
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
...
```

To log the user out, all you have to do is delete the key from the session and call `flush()`:

```
def logout(...):
    try:
        del request.session['user_id']
        request.session.flush()
    except KeyError:
        pass
   ...
```

Comment: thank you how i can check request.session['user_id'] in page html like {% if user.is_authenticated %}

Comment: @YoussefPu You can try `{% if request.session.user_id %}` to check if a user_id exists in the session object. That would tell you if the user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 3):

You have to first obtain the user through `authenticate` and then call `login` with the returned user

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login

Example from django's documentation:

```python
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
        ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you i'm using database mongodb can't use login function because mongodb doesn't support django authentication

Comment: I read too fast and didn't realize you're bulding your own User class. I think that if you provide a class with the same external interface as the built in User class it will work. Because session handling is done by the middleware and not the User class. You can have ideas by looking at the source code of login: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#login